# Can we lower the Requirement for #Reputation to add a comment?

Tags: support, new-users

Can we lower the Requirement for #Reputation to add a comment?  Right now, I think the setting is 50 Reputation will allow you the Comment-privilege.  We have an increase in the flux of new users, and if they have <100 Reputation, we shouldn't reprimand these users so harshly for writing "low quality posts" because they resorted to writing a **solution** because they don't have the <kbd>comment</kbd>-privilege.

Can we lower our Privilege settings to create a more friendly atmosphere for new users?

Comment: I tend to upvote new users on questions and true answers more liberal to get them 50+ rep asap. Maybe thats an alternative.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that it should be lowered.  Commenting is a privilege that is gained after a certain amount of participation which is acceptable to me.

I don't think that they should be reprimanded harshly.  Sometimes short, text-only internet interactions are taken the wrong way and seem harsher than they are intended. Sometimes they are harsh, though.

Sometimes the non answers by low rep users are really new questions and users without enough rep for commenting can always ask a separate question.

We leave a comment instructing them that their answer is not an answer and that they should refer to the about page or something to that effect.  It is reasonable, in my opinion, to expect someone to take the time to read about how the site works.

Comment: then can we stop badgering new users for "low quality" posts?

Comment: I don't see it as badgering them.  I see it more as helping and educating them about how the site works.

Comment: Agree with Peter and Robert here - the rep requirement on commenting is a useful check on 'me too' comments. There is a little moderator overhead in converting answers to comments occasionally, but it's not bad.

Answer (score 7):

New users can ask and answer questions, as well as comment on their ***own*** posts as well as a ***any*** posts that answer questions they own. That's a lot of activity requiring no reputation or experience at all.

Beyond that, comments fulfill a very *specific* purpose which is easily misused before someone has a bit experience with the site. The reputation system is a rough measurement of that experience. It doesn't take much reputation to access those features, so we ask that users simply hold off using feature that can easily be misused (comments, voting, editing, closing, etc), at least until they have a bit more experience using the site.

Answer (score 0):

I agree... I remember when I first started here, I was confused as to how to respond to a comment.  I instead went and just created an answer to respond to a comment.  I had to basically do a full answer than explicitly respond to the concerns in other comments.  So my answer was a close duplicate to another person's answer, but addressing the comments in that answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to bring this up again because every couple days there is someone asking questions like this in an **Answer**:

[image]

And I totally understand their intention. It would be way less disturbing if we had these as comments. What could go wrong if everybody could comment?

Comment: Lots could go wrong. You need to earn a minimal amount of trust to gain this privilege. I didn't vote down but I do agree with Peter.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I understand, but isn't it wrong that you can ask questions and create answers without being trusted, but you can't comment?

Comment: You can comment on your own posts and answers to them. If you spend even a little time learning how to use the site, it would be easy to post a question linking to what you found and indicating where you are stuck.

Comment: have to agree here... I'm just getting annoyed, seems like I need to stay calm :)

Comment: I really think we need to stick to the 50 rep limit as it isn't much to earn - a couple of reasonably well written questions or answers will soon earn that much rep. Most importantly they can comment on their own questions and answers without any problem. With the 'me too' comments I don't understand how it is meant to help by adding it when an answer isn't there.